# Google+ Moments.insert - Unauthorized Error

Tags: c#, google-plus, google-api-dotnet-client

According to the docuemtntation for [Moments.insert](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert) with the Google+ API autentication with the following scope is required

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
```

I am authenticating with all of the possible PlusService scopes but i am still getting the following error

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Unauthorized [401] Errors [
>     Message[Unauthorized] Location[ - ] Reason[unauthorized]
>   Domain[global]

```
 //Scopes for use with Google+ API
 // activating Google+ API in console
 // Documentation:  https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth
 string[] scopes = new string[] {
    PlusService.Scope.PlusLogin,
    PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail,
    PlusService.Scope.UserinfoProfile
 };

 string _client_id = "2046123799103-d0vpdthl4ms0soutcrpe036ckqn7rfpn.apps.googleusercontent.com";
 string _client_secret = "NDmluNfTgUk6wgmy7cFo64RV";

 PlusService service = null;
 UserCredential credential = null;

 try {
    // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets {
        ClientId = _client_id, ClientSecret = _client_secret
    },
    scopes,
    Environment.UserName,
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore("Daimto.GooglePlus.Auth.Store")).Result;
 } catch (Exception ex) {
    //If the user hits cancel you wont get access.
    if (ex.InnerException.Message.IndexOf("access_denied") != -1) {
        Console.WriteLine("User declined access");
        Console.ReadLine();
        return;
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Unknown Authentication Error:" + ex.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
        return;
    }
 }

 // Now we create a Google service. All of our requests will be run though this.
 service = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Google Plus Sample",
 });


 Moment body = new Moment();
 body.Type = "http://schema.org/AddAction";

 ItemScope itemScope = new ItemScope();
 itemScope.Id = "target-id-1";
 itemScope.Type = "http://schema.org/AddAction";
 itemScope.Name = "The Google+ Platform";
 itemScope.Description = "A page that describes just how awesome Google+ is!";
 itemScope.Image = "https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/examples/thing.png";
 body.Object = itemScope;

 try {
    var l = service.Moments.Insert(body, "me", MomentsResource.InsertRequest.CollectionEnum.Vault);
    l.Execute();
 } catch (Exception ex) {
    int i = 1;
 }
```

I have tested authentication and it is working i am able to list activities and other things.   Its only inserting moments that is giving me this error.   I have also tried doing this in PHP and am getting the same error.   What am I missing?

Update: I found something in the documentation for [moments.insert](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert)

> When authenticating for moments.insert, you must include the
>   [data-requestvisibleactions](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/reference#button_attr_requestvisibleactions) parameter to specify which types of App
>   Activities your application will write.

I have not figured out yet how to set this data-requestvisibleactions.

Comment: It's WEIRD. I agree. Try adding the ["profile" scope](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#profile).
It is mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#deprecated-scopes) that both UserInfoEmail and UserInfoProfile are deprecated.

Comment: @peleyal profile doesnt apear as a scope in  PlusService.Scope could itb be missing from the client lib?   do you know what data-requestvisibleactions could be?

Comment: Looks like for it to work with java you have to do some kinda hackie add it to the url https://developers.google.com/+/web/app-activities/

Comment: Can you just add "profile" (string), and check that out? Did it work for you eventually? I mean using the link you just shared...

Comment: No i still haven't gotten it to work.  "profile" scope doesn't help same error.

Comment: I may try and do this the hard way with out the client lib.  But really i think it should work some how with the client lib. I have yet to find something thats not supported by the .net client lib.

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed, you need to add the `request_visible_actions` parameter to the request. Most of the other OAuth libraries from Google have added a shortcut to do this, but it looks like the .NET library hasn't. For example, the PHP library has [setRequestVisibleActions()](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php#L360).

Internally, the convenience method `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()` calls `AuthorizationCodeFlow.CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest()` to generate the URL used in the call. You can subclass `AuthorizationCodeFlow` and `AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl` (which it returns) to add the parameter in question and then go through the flow more directly.

You can see an example of how to do this at https://github.com/gguuss/google-dotnet-demo/blob/master/AuthWithAppActivities/Program.cs

You can also use a [Google+ Sign-In button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow) to do the initial auth flow and pass the one-time code to the server, which can then proceed to turn this into a valid token. Since the Sign-In button has the `data-requestvisibleactions` attribute, this will take care of that part of the auth for you.