# How to post media on google plus through google api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, google-plus

```
private void googleplue()
{
    Moment body = new Moment();
    ItemScope itemScope = new ItemScope();

    itemScope.Id = "replacewithuniqueforaddtarget";
    itemScope.Image = "http://www.google.com/s2/static/images/GoogleyEyes.png";
    itemScope.Type = "";
    itemScope.Description = "The description for the action";
    itemScope.Name = "An example of add activity";

    body.Object = itemScope;
    body.Type = "http://schema.org/AddAction";

    MomentsResource.InsertRequest insert =
        new MomentsResource.InsertRequest(
            plusService,
            body,
            userId,
            MomentsResource.Collection.Vault);
   // Moment wrote = insert.Fetch();
}
```

I tried this but not work please give me any other solution.

Comment: What do you mean by _not work_? You get any exception or error message?

Answer (score 1):

Moment isn't the same as posting to Google+ timeline its not possible to post to the Google+ timeline. see  [Issue 41: Write access to the streams](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=41)

In order to post moments which isn't the same thing,  you need to be able to set `request_visible_actions`  as part of the authentication process and it doesn't appear that its possible to do with with the current version of the C# client library [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472937/google-moments-insert-unauthorized-error)

If you want to post moments and not write to a user time line then your going to have to figure out how to send the `request_visible_actions` as part of your authentication.  if you do figure out how to do that please post the answer on my question.